# Другой контроллер для CActiveForm

Tags: ооп, php, yii

Виджет CActiveForm, как правило, начинается с этого:

$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                        'id'=>'additional-form',
                        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
                    ));

Где $this - Это объект, соответсвующий текущему контроллеру (если я правильно понимаю). А если мне нужно вместо текущего контроллера использовать данные для формы из другого контроллера (например для страницы, на которой сразу несколько форм), то что нужно написать после $form= ?

Прошу сильно не ругать ибо только постигаю ООП при работе с yii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно я не правильно вас понял, но данные формы (в том числе и ошибки валидации) ведь берутся не из контроллера, а из моделей. Т.е. вызвали виджет, который просто сформирует в html теги формы и пропишет ей указанные параметры (а также создаст модель, которая нам предоставит некоторые удобные методы), а далее начинаете формировать саму форму:

```
<div><?= $form->textField($user, 'name') ?></div>
<div><?= $form->error($user, 'name')?></div>
```

где $user - это модель CModel.

Соответственно, для создания второй формы просто выбираете новое имя переменной и заново вызываете beginWindget(), а вместо модели $user используете какую-то еще. Ну а модели передаются в представления как и остальные переменные.

Можно даже не пользоваться виджетом и строить форму [через методы хелперов](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/form.view)

Answer (score 1):

> Где $this - Это объект, соответсвующий
> текущему контроллеру (если я правильно
> понимаю). А если мне нужно вместо
> текущего контроллера использовать
> данные для формы из другого
> контроллера (например для страницы, на
> которой сразу несколько форм), то что
> нужно написать после $form= ?

Все правильно, кроме одного: в контроллере не должно быть данных вообще.
Сам по себе контроллер существует в единственном числе. Один запрос - один контроллер. Symfony позволяет рендерить вывод другого контроллера в текущий, но в Yii такого нет и проще на этом этапе принять это за данность. Контроллер вообще должен быть некоей сущностью, которая знает, где и какие подтягивать данные в том или ином случае, но не хранит их, а просто передает представлению. Идеальный контроллер - это три строчки: создание нужной модели, нахождение данных с помощью модели, рендеринг представления с одновременной передачей данных.
CActiveForm создается контроллером, но данные для нее предоставляет не контроллер, а ***объект модели***. Поэтому при рендеринге необходимо передать в представление (частью которого является CActiveForm) все те модели, для которых необходимо создать формы. Сама CACtiveForm никак к контроллеру не привязана (она просто создается методом контроллером, но привязок не сохраняет). Если же требуются еще какие-то данные, то они должны быть найдены текущим контроллером, и переданы в представление.

Типичный стэк с использованием CACtiveForm будет выглядеть так:

```
class UserController extends CController {
    // действия
    public function actionEdit($id)
    {
        $user = User::model()->findByPk($id);
        $this->render('edit', array('user' => $user, 'customNote' => 'Eat borsch thrice a day')); // передаем загруженную модель юзера и какие-то дополнительные данные
    }
    // другие действия

}
```

edit.php

```
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm');

$form->label($user, 'login'); // первым аргументом CActiveForm принимает саму модель, второй - название атрибута
$form->textField($user, 'login'); // все данные передаются внутри модели
$form->error($user, 'login');

// другие поля

$this->endWidget(); // $this, он же текущий контроллер, вызывается только для того, чтобы создать и закончить CActiveForm

?>
<div class="note"><?php echo $customNote; ?></div> // передача дополнительных данных
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутое объяснение! Очень многое встало на свои места). Но именно vanchester подсказал мне, что нужно обратить внимание на другую модель. Хотя можно считать, что вы оба ответили правильно.